# An answer to an unposed question

Tags: discussion

I was very tempted to answer [Suggestions for reducing the transmission rate?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/355489) with the following.  In fact I did, but I deleted it again, because I do realize that there is nothing mathematical in my answer, and it goes into a completely different direction than what was actually asked for in the body of the question.

However, I do think it may be an important factoid.  I really couldn't believe at first that what I describe below was reality.

I have no idea where this fits, or if it fits anywhere at all.  I am not asking a question here, but I feel obliged to share it.

---

I have one rather practical answer, which does not answer the question in the body, but possibly in the title.

I was very surprised to learn that a (small) hospital in my home town was doing their scheduling ("rostering" might be the correct term, but I don't know) by hand.

They were clever enough to ask for help just in time. Again surprisingly: informally via a mathematician they knew privately. Thus, they now have a professional university team developing a plan that fits their new needs - minimal service, minimizing the probability that a large portion of their staff simultaneously drops out.

I guess that such a strategy might also make sense for other community services, who might not even be aware of this fact.

(Disclaimer: I am not helping with the implementation, but I was lucky to know someone who knew someone who was a professional in this field, who luckily agreed to do it.)

Comment: I don't want to discuss this particular example, but I think it is commonly accepted to post an answer, which doesn't answer the question but provides useful related information, if it's explicit from the beginning. For instance a number of answers start with *"An extended comment"*, or *"A partial answer"*, and one can imagine other variants. It's likely to be upvoted if useful, and downvoted if unrelated or not useful.